# Spring @Transactional cause NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-transactions

A guy ask me for help him resolve a strange bug in security service of his spring boot app, after hours of trail I manage to fix the bug but I really have no idea what happen. Please look at these classes:

Class `User` : user infomation in database

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"user_name"})})
public class User extends DateAudit implements Serializable {
  // Id, username, password and constructor... not really important

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
  private Set<Role> role = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Class `UserDto` : implement Spring's interface for manage user credential

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserDto implements org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails {
  private long id;
  private String Username;
  @JsonIgnore
  private String password;
  private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;

  public static UserDto create(User user) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = user.getRole().stream()
      .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName().name())).collect(Collectors.toList());

    return new UserDto(user.getId(), user.getUserName(), user.getPassword(), authorities);
  }

  // implement interface's methods, only getters, not important
}
```

Class `CustomUserService` : Auth service

```
@Service
public class CustomUserService implements org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService {
  private final UserRepository userRepository;

  @Autowired
  public CustomUserService(UserRepository userRepository) {
     this.userRepository = userRepository;
  }

  @Override
  @Transactional
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userRepository.findUserByUserName(userName).orElseThrow(() -> {
    return null;
    });
    return UserDto.create(user);
  }
}
```

Full source code can be found here (it is only a simple spring boot app with some classes) : https://github.com/raizo000/admin_project (his repo uses embedded tomcat, I've tried to change it to jetty but it is not the cause)

When I run code  the first time with these 3 classes. The line

```
return UserDto.create(user);
```

Give me a `NoClassDefFoundError` :

```
WARN 7252 --- [qtp223566397-22] org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel     : /login

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/example/admin/dto/UserDto
    at com.example.admin.services.CustomUserService.loadUserByUsername(CustomUserService.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.admin.services.CustomUserService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b9234a59.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
....
```

I have checked the jar file, there is a UserDto.class file in the right directory.

Remove the `@Transactional` help fix the error but cause another lazily initialize error and I end up change `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` in `User` class to `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` as a quick fix.

Why adding Transactional can cause a NoClassDefFoundError? Do remove Transactional is the right solution or there is a better fix?

Comment: could you please put @Transactional in class header and let us know what happsens?

Comment: I'm really very confused now, after the code work, neither add @Transactional  again at the method level or class level as you mention cause the error. I try `mvn clean` then restart the app but I can't make the bug happen again!

Comment: yep, so package clean was solved. the dependencies weren't found based on  @Transactional interface..

Comment: I still don't get it. Please explain it in your answer to make it clearer.

Comment: done @HaiHoang .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a class is not found, the first thing that you should make is clean and build.
Because, the last build is saving some dependency.
So the [@Transactional](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html) @interface was not found in some corrupt package.
A rebuild(clean build) solves it.

Comment: maybe it is a rare / strange issue of maven. because every build I always run `mvn clean install` . Seem like the first time I remove @Transactional fix the package then the error never happen again.